# The answer is the key

Tags: word, steganography

**Firstly I reside. Secondly the letter exists towards the expression resolution.**

---

**Notes:** The above two sentences fully and unambiguously describe the answer. Also, I'm not sure if this qualifies as a riddle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Answer:**

> F

**Explanation:**

> Each letter of the words spells out 
>  
>  **FIRSTLETTER** 
>  
>  Firstly 
>  I 
>  Reside 
>  Secondly 
>  The 
>  Letter 
>  Exists 
>  Towards 
>  The 
>  Expression 
>  Resolution 
>  
>  F resides first in the sentence, and secondly it is a part of the resolution of the answer, being in FIRSTLETTER.

Comment: Close enough I guess. I'll post the answer I had in mind below.

Comment: Very nice riddle and  clever answer. If we're being picky it seems to me that "F" is a more logical answer, "first letter" only the way to get there. There's nothing on the problem statement that clarifies that the answer  is (exclusively) firstly in each word. And the second phrase refers to "the letter", which can be interpreted as the answer  being a single letter.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is

> FIRST LETTER

which is cool because

> the title suggests that the answer is the key, and that is true - the answer tells you how to solve the question (by taking the first letter of every word)

Firstly I reside

> This isn't a cryptic clue, it tells you where to look for the answer, as in *I reside first*. Also a subtle hint that the answer begins with *first*.

Secondly the letter exists towards the expression resolution.

> Secondly the *letter* exists towards the expression resolution, which is also true because *letter* is the second word in the phrase.

Comment: Well I was 9% correct, only explained it for one letter. :P

Answer (score 0):

To expand on other answers:

> "Firstly I reside": This could refer to the letter I, which looks like the upright part of the letter F.

and

> "Secondly the letter exists towards the expression resolution.": This could refer to an equals sign in a mathematical expression and describ the horizontal bars of the F.